# How to debug the Android facebook messenger app webview?

Tags: facebook-messenger

I have a pwa(Angular website) which is loading the contents in Android Chrome but the same pwa is not loading properly in facebook messenger app once opened from itself by clicking the shared url.

So, I want to debug and fine the issue in facebook messenger android app.
Please help me to find a way to troubleshoot the issue in my pwa in facebook messenger app.